# viewing obj texture in three.js leads to vastly different results than e.g. Blender or Windows 3d Viewer

Tags: three.js

I am importing an obj+mtl+jpg into a three.js scene. Unfortunately the texture is not shown nicely but with rather annoying grey areas at the handle that do not occur when I load the model in Windows 3d viewer or Blender.

Surely looks will depend on exact rendering with lights etc to a degree but this is quite annoying as it makes creating models hard as I never know what I really get before loading it in the three.js viewer.  So I wonder how to close that gap in rendering to a more reasonable degree.

Rendering in three.js is pretty common at the moment without postprocessing or any such things:

```
...
var renderer = new WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
var camera = new PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect_ratio, 0.1, 1000);
...
scene.add(new AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1));
var pointLight = new PointLight(0x404040, 0.5, 20);
scene.add(pointLight);
```

First picture is from three.js rendering. Second from Windows 3d Viewer and 3rd from Blender.

[image: handle in three.js based viewer rendering]
[image: handle in windows 3d viewer rendering]
[image: handle in blender rendering]

Comment: So what's the question? You want to close that gap, but what's the result you expect? It looks like those dark areas are some sort of baked ambient occlusion. Might be part of your textures.

Comment: Can you please share the OBJ asset (with MTL and textures) in this thread?